# average of random variable

Tags: probability

Assume X$_1$, ... , X$_n$ are i.i.d distributed random variables. And each them of has the same probability density function as f(x) = $\frac{1}{\pi}$$\frac{1}{1+ x^2}$. How can we compute the probability density function for X = $\frac{1}{n}$ $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$X$_i$?

Some idea is to write the cumulative distribution function:

F$_{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}$(a) = P(X$_1$ + X$_2$ + ... + X$_n$ $\leq$ a) = $\idotsint$ f$_{X_1}$(x$_1$)f$_{X_2}$(x$_2$) $\cdots$ $\cdots$ f$_{X_n}$(x$_n$)d$_{x_1}$d$_{x_2}$$\cdots$d$_{x_n}$

But feel hard to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using the **characteristic function** (if you know about this). Note that $X_i$ come from a **standard Cauchy distribution** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution; $x_0=0$ and $\gamma=1$ there for the standard Cauchy distribution). See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238246/what-is-the-distribution-of-sample-means-of-a-cauchy-distribution for a proof with the characteristic function.

Comment: thanks, is there any way to calculate it? btw, why can we say they have same pdfs if their characteristic functions are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also has density $\frac 1 {\pi} \frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$. The best way to prove this is to use characteristic functions: since $Ee^{itX_1}=e^{-|t|}$ and  $(e^{-|\frac t n|})^{n}=e^{-|t|}$ we get the conclusion easily.

Comment: Thanks, btw, how can we prove the characteristic function for standard Cauchy distribution?

Comment: ignore previous comment. any suggestion on traditional way to calculate it rather than using characteristic functions?